# There was no endpoint listening at .. Unable to connect to the remote server

Tags: .net, wcf, service, service-reference

Hi all actually it was working last week but I don't know whats happened and now its not working.

The problem is I have two solutions in different machines. The first one has 2 projects one is WCF service project and the other one is wpf project which uses this localhost service and works fine. however when other machine wants to connect the server which is not localhost it gives this error.

> There was an error downloading
>   '(address):8732/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'.
>   Unable to connect to the remote server No connection could be made
>   because the target machine actively refused it(address):8732 Metadata
>   contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
>   '(address):8732/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1'.
>   There was no endpoint listening at
>   (address):8732/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1 that
>   could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address
>   or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
>   Unable to connect to the remote server No connection could be made
>   because the target machine actively refused it (address):8732 If the
>   service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution
>   and adding the service reference again.

Ive pinged my address and it sends and receives data
I turned off the windows firewall

and my app.config is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService1" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                    allowCookies="false">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                        enabled="false" />
                    <security mode="Message">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                            algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
                <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService11" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                    allowCookies="false">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                        enabled="false" />
                    <security mode="Message">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                            algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService1"
                contract="ServiceReference1.IService1" name="WSHttpBinding_IService1">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService11"
                contract="ServiceReference2.IService1" name="WSHttpBinding_IService11">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3):

Why do you have same endpoint defined two times on your client using exactly same address?

```
<client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService1"
                contract="ServiceReference1.IService1" name="WSHttpBinding_IService1">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService11"
                contract="ServiceReference2.IService1" name="WSHttpBinding_IService11">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
```